# Any way to make a bundle required with Knoplerfish?

Tags: osgi, knopflerfish

Is there any way to abort the startup of Knoplerfish if a specific bundle fails to initialize? By default, a FrameworkErrorEvent is printed to the console and the framework continues to load.

**init.xargs**

```
-initlevel 80
-istart my-required-bundle.jar
```

**console output**

```
[stdout] Installed and started: file:jars/my-required-bundle.jar (id#34)
[stdout] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent bundle #34
[stdout] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent throwable:
[stderr] org.osgi.framework.BundleException: BundleActivator start failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard OSGi way to do this, since there is no standard way to tell the framework what bundles to install (that is up to a launcher). There is also no standard way to get notified of this event, so you can act on it. If Knopflerfish does not provide a specific system property or something similar to handle this, I see two routes you could take.

- Build your own launcher. Instantiate a `org.knopflerfish.framework.Main`, configure it (there is some information in the readme on this), and install the bundles by getting a `BundleContext` from the framework. You can then catch `BundleException`s that come from the bundle's `start()` method, and abort the startup when it has type `RESOLVE_ERROR`.
- Create a bundle that waits a specific amount of time, and then inspects the framework to see whether all bundles have started (you can get a list of all currently installed bundles from the `BundleContext`). If one of them is not in state `INSTALLED`, you can stop the framework by stopping the system bundle (i.e., bundle 0).